# My code is working fine in Python, how to pass parameter values from HTML?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

The below code is working fine in python, but how to pass parameter values from html?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('Dataprofile.csv')

# run the profile report
profile = df.profile_report(title='Pandas Profiling Report')

# save the report as html file
profile.to_file(output_file="pandas_profiling1.html")

# save the report as json file
profile.to_file(output_file="pandas_profiling2.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of to_file use to_html.
df.to_html("Table.html")
You can style it with CSS in the HTML file.